# How do I enumerate options assigned to a type?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, types

A Node.js package I'm using has a method that takes an argument required to be of a type that via IntelliSense I can see is defined with a typescript declaration in the form:

```
export declare type ArgType = 'A' | 'B' | 'C';
```

I'd like to call the package method using each permissible value for this argument in turn; in other words, something in the form:

```
['A','B','C'].forEach((v) => packageObject.packageMethod(v));
```

except I'd like to avoid hard-coding a static copy of the list of options.

Comment: How _would_ you like to provide the list of options? Why the mystery behind what the package is? Seems an odd use case "_to call the package method using each permissible value_", is this for testing or what purpose?

Comment: Is this `typescript` related? It seems so - afaik, if you want to programmatically operate on type, you'll need to delve into the [compiler api](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API). However, "every value" may often not be feasible, imagine e.g. `number`, you'd have to try 2**64 values.

Comment: @ASDFGerte yes, well deduced. Shame if it is really that exotic an excercise to achieve. In this case, the type options are references to different servers used by a proprietary web API accessed by the package. I thought it was quite nice how readily IntelliSense offered me the selection of options as autocompletions, so thought accessing them programmatically ought to be moderately feasible.

Comment: It's maybe something new to learn, but no mythical arts - it's an "api", so the fundamental work is already done for you.

Comment: Unless the module exports them as values (e.g. an array of permissible strings), you're out of luck and will have to hard-code the list yourself. TypeScript type information is not available at runtime. (Unless you use something like [the *reify-ts* package](https://github.com/hchauvin/reify-ts) to generate code)

Comment: @Bergi drat. My informal understanding of JS, mostly from a distance, wouldn't have led me to guess it had such a strong distinction between compile-time and runtime. But as it is, I can see why what I was trying to do is not so straightforward.

Comment: @Will Well, it's not JavaScript, it's TypeScript :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you have the ability to modify the package, you can derive the union of strings from a readonly array of string literals, and also export the array for use in runtime code:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=2#code/PTAEFMA8AcHsCcAu4AmoCGBnUA3dAbAV3GwApDN0AjfcDRUeQgO0QEsBbcASgCgo4SUAGNYzTAwnw2zAOYBBeLOwBeUAG0A5PM0AaUJoBCegwGFNAXQzZR4xAG5evEBBgJkaLKBZsxoWABmoFIyyqCkzLAMFNS09Iws7Fx8Au6giACe0HSKsgAqWXRqmdmBwYjScrmY6syEHFTg8Bb2oC4ARPLtoAA+oO2G3X3tpu1OqUIBLMLsfgHM4ehKAFyguQXZ3Ks4sGxoAN68oG1gAHTnvAC+vEA)

```ts
// exported as values (usable at runtime)
export const stringArgs = ['A', 'B', 'C'] as const;

// exported as union of strings (not usable at runtime)
export type ArgType = typeof stringArgs[number]; // "A" | "B" | "C"

export function fn (arg: ArgType): void {
  // ...
}
```

Otherwise, you'll have to parse the values using the [compiler API](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API), as [mentioned by @ASDFGerte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69968232/how-do-i-enumerate-options-assigned-to-a-type#comment123683625_69968232).

Comment: Regrettably I don't have that ability! But seems like the appropriate solution were the package authors anticipating the options being enumerated at runtime

Comment: Send a PR! I encountered [a similar situation recently](https://github.com/dyedgreen/deno-sqlite/pull/156), and the maintainer was happy to merge.